# Specify two variables as output operands for one result from vector register?

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly, arm64

I'm trying to use inline ASM to speed up some multiplications. The device is Aarch64 and it has vector multiplication available. The multiplier performs 64 x 64 → 128-bit multiplication.

Here's how the multiplication looks if the output operand is a SIMD/vector register:

```
uint64x2_t r = {0,0}, a = {2,4}, b = {6,8};
__asm__ __volatile__
(
   "pmull %0.1q, %1.1d, %2.1d;"
   : "=w" (r)
   : "w" (a[0]), "w" (b[0])
   : "cc"
);
```

How can I remove the output operand, which is `"=w" (r)`, and change it to two *D* registers that are backed by variables (I'm making this up because I'm not sure what its supposed to look like):

```
uint64x2_t r = {0,0}, a = {2,4}, b = {6,8};
uint64x1_t r1, r2;

__asm__ __volatile__
(
   "pmull %0.1q, %1.1d, %2.1d;"
   : "=w.1d" (r1), "=w.1d" (r2), 
   : "w" (a[0]), "w" (b[0])
   : "cc"
);
```

Or:

```
uint64x2_t r = {0,0}, a = {2,4}, b = {6,8};
uint64_t r1, r2;

__asm__ __volatile__
(
   "pmull %0.1q, %1.1d, %2.1d;"
   : "=w.1d" (r1), "=w.1d" (r2), 
   : "w" (a[0]), "w" (b[0])
   : "cc"
);
```

The idea is, after the multiplication, I have two 64-bit values `r1` and `r2`, and I don't need to do anything else other than use them.

Comment: _"How can I remove the output operand... and change it to two D registers"_ - do you want the "petition ARM to change the architecture so that that `pmull` takes two output registers instead of one, then wait 3 years for CPUs that do that" way, or the "add an explicit `dup` to the inline asm and hamper local optimisation" way?

Comment: @Notlikethat - I was hoping for the GCC way, similar to the way it handles pairs of registers or clobbering X86's EBX during CPUID so it uses that twisted register redirection.

Comment: Is this really a question of gcc though?  If the ARM architecture doesn't provide a way to access the 2 parts of the vector register, there's not much gcc can do about it.  At best it could add a constraint to simulate it (generating the appropriate ARM instruction).  And if that's where you end up, you might as well do that yourself.

Comment: @jww The point I was obliquely making is that "pairs of registers" is where you're going fundamentally wrong. [The AArch64 SIMD/FP register layout is not the same as AArch32](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.den0024a/CEGDJGGC.html).